# Editing a java snap

Tags: java, packaging, snap

I'm trying to change the source of a java snap. Here's what I do:

1. Download the sample project.

   ```
   svn export https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/trunk/demos/java-hello-world
   ```
2. Build the snap named java-hello-world.

   ```
   cd java-hello-world  
   snapcraft
   ```
3. Install the snap.

   ```
   sudo snap install java-hello-world_0_amd64.snap --dangerous
   ```
4. Run the snap.

   ```
   java-hello-world.hello
   ```

   The output is `Hello World` as expected.

Now I want to change the snap so it prints "Hello Snap" instead of "Hello World". Here's what I do:

1. Edit `java-hello-world/snap/snapcraft.yaml`. Change grade to `devel` and confinement to `devmode`.
2. Edit `java-hello-world/src/oata/HelloWorld.java`. Change line 7 to `System.out.println("Hello Snap");`.
3. Iterate over the snap.

   ```
   snapcraft prime
   sudo snap try --devmode prime/
   ```

   The output is `Hello World`. I would like to have the output `Hello Snap` here.

What I'm doing wrong: There are two things in the build process which seem suspicious to me.

1. When running snapcraft prime it says:

   ```
   Skipping pull local (already ran)  
   Skipping build local (already ran)  
   Skipping stage local (already ran)  
   Skipping prime local (already ran)  
   Skipping pull wrapper (already ran)  
   Skipping build wrapper (already ran)  
   Skipping stage wrapper (already ran)  
   Skipping prime wrapper (already ran)
   ```

   I guess skipping all these steps also includes skipping reading and compiling the file `java-hello-world/src/oata/HelloWorld.java`. Thats 
   why the output is still the same after editing the file. How can I not skip that step? [The tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/create-first-snap?utm_source=snapcraft.io&utm_medium=buildfirstsnap&utm_campaign=tutorials#3) says:

   > Note: The different steps of snapcraft are: pull (download source for
   >   all parts), build, stage (consolidate installed files of all parts),
   >   prime (distill down to just the desired files), snap (create a snap
   >   out of the prime/ directory). Each steps depends on the previous one
   >   to be completed".

   I tried to `snapcraft pull` instead of `prime`, but the result is the same.
2. When running `snapcraft` the first time, `ant` gives a warning.

   ```
   [javac] /home/username/Java/java-hello-world/parts/local/build/build.xml:19: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set,
   defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
   ```

   I don't know what `defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last` means. So that might be the problem. "set to false for repeatable builds" should
   be ok, because thats what [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103384/ant-warning-includeantruntime-was-not-set).

How can I refresh the source of the snap after changing it?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Clean the previous build

   ```
   snapcraft clean
   ```

   But when you have big project you may want only for that part

   ```
   snapcraft clean local
   ```
2. Rebuild again

   ```
   snapcraft
   ```